# Google Analytics - button onclick tracking

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

The specific code for the button placed on my site is provided by third-party and redirects the user to the third-party website. 
I want to track in Google Analytics the number of times this button is pressed. The goal is to know how many people reached that third-party website.

Here is code for the button:

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, kjs;
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = 'https://kaspi.kz/kaspibutton/widget/ks-wi_ext.js';
kjs = document.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]
kjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, kjs);
}(document, 'script', 'KS-Widget'));</script>

     <div class="ks-widget"
     data-template="button"
     data-merchant-sku="103368" 
     data-merchant-code="BELVETER" 
     data-city="351010000">
     </div>`
```

Please help where should I place the onclick code. I tried to put it everywhere but it does not work. However it works perfectly for  links but not for the above button.

Comment: Please show the GA code you are using and where are you placing it where it isn't working.

Comment: `<div class="ks-widget"  data-template="button" data-merchant-sku="103368" data-merchant-code="BELVETER" data-city="351010000" onclick="ga('send', 'event', '5SE_16_Rose', 'Kaspi', '0', 1);"></div>`

Comment: Have you considered using Google Tag Manager? You can place your GA code there and set onclick events fairly simple